# Is there something wrong with my setInterval function Implementation?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm currently trying to create a stopwatch component using React Native and the setInterval function to increment a counter and set the new value to state like so:

**Play Function(this runs after hitting the play button)**

```
  const [isRunning, setisRunning] = useRecoilState(runState);
  const [time, setTime] = useRecoilState(timeState);
  const [timerRef, setTimerRef] = useState(0);

  const Play = useCallback(() => {
  window.clearInterval(interval);                       //clear the interval 
  if (isRunning === false) {                           //set the isRunning state to true
  setisRunning((isRunning) => !isRunning);

  interval = window.setInterval(() => {               //setInterval operation
    setTime((previousTime) => previousTime + 1);
  }, 100);

  setTimerRef(interval);                             //setTimer reference to pause
}
}, [time]);
```

**Pause Function(this runs after hitting the pause button)**

```
  const Pause = () => {
  if (isRunning === true) {
  setisRunning((isRunning) => !isRunning);
  window.clearInterval(timerRef);
  }
  };
```

My problem is that the timer tends to speed up erratically an as such I'm not able to use the time value passed. I'm not sure where I am going wrong, kindly assist.

Comment: when you call `window.clearInterval(interval);`, interval is undefined so you are not clearing the interval. Since you're saving a reference of the interval when you call `setTimerRef` you can maybe use that aswell for clearing the interval: `window.clearInterval(timerRef.current);`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so Iv've run into this quite recently in my next.js project. The correct way to do it seems like something like that:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    console.log('This will run every second!');
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

See for example [here](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/setinterval-in-react-components-using-hooks)